# Email per day - mental practitioner

Tags: clinical-psychology

How many emails per day does a mental practitioner receive per day?
I do not find an estimate. There are anecdotal accounts, such as [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-good-life/201108/dealing-e-mail-the-24-hour-rule) and [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-mysteries-love/201902/is-why-i-haven-t-replied-your-email); here answers go from 50 to 200 emails per day.
There is a nice [APA report from 2015,](https://www.apa.org/workforce/publications/15-health-service-providers) but it does not discuss this aspect.
I am looking at the [general population of workers](https://www.lifewire.com/how-many-emails-are-sent-every-day-1171210) as well, although this approach implies an increase in the variance, and thus in the uncertainty on whether the answer I could get is similar to the answer I would get from practitioners; here it seems that office workers receive 40 email per day.
My curiosity started after I read some articles (e.g. this [one](https://kspope.com/ethics/email.php)) on ethical concerns about emails, so I started to wonder how much a mental practitioner might spend per day reading emails.

I am not a psychologist or neuroscientist, but I reading on this topic for some research on time consumption in the occupation.

Any insight or reading reference would be very welcomed!